# Are there ads that I can add to my android app without market link?

Tags: android, google-play, ads

Is their an0 android app ads library that I can use in my app without the need to publish the app in the market?

Comment: Yes, there are still many parts of the world without Market access. Surely someone is willing to serve ads to apps installed via other means.

Comment: Why not also publish it to the market? You could restrict it to only the country/countries you care about?

Comment: cause I want to start from a small comunity and see if my app is useful and good

Comment: what ad providers have you found that require you to use the android market? Can you post a link to the terms that indicate you must distribute via the Market? I've not heard of any that have such a limitation.

Comment: admob - http://www.google.com/ads/admob/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to publish your application on the Market in order to use AdMob ads. Just register on the AdMob site and get your code to use when displaying ads.
2. I don't see any relevance between being small company and using Android Market, about 80% or more of Android Market submissions are made by singe developers, there's absolutely nothing wrong about publishing your personal application. I can even tell, it's really helpful to get a feedback from market users, especially if you don't have many people to beta-test your application.